# How to dispatch a thunk action with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Follow the [official doc](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#usage-with-redux-thunk), I make a redux thunk function with typescript.

```
// store/user/thunk.ts

function loginApi(user: UserState) {
  return fetch(
    `${baseUrl}/login?user=${user.userName}&pwd=${user.pwd}`
  )
    .then(res => res.json())
}

export const thunkLogin = (
  user: UserState
): ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, Action<string>> => async dispatch => {
  const asyncResp = await loginApi(user)
  dispatch(
    updateUser({
      loggedIn: asyncResp.isloggedIn,
      userName: user.userName,
      userPwd: user.userPwd
    })
  )
}
```

As the official document say, I dispatch a action like this and it has no problem here.

```
// app.tsx

import { updateUser } from '../store/action'

interface Props {
  updateUser: typeof updateUser
}

interface State {
  userName: string
  userPwd: string
}

class AppComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.updateUser({
      userName: this.state.userName,
      userPwd: this.state.userPwd
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <TextInput
        style={style.userTextInput}
        value={this.state.userName}
        onChangeText={(userName) => this.setState({ userName })}
        placeholder="input userName"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={style.userTextInput}
        value={this.state.userPwd}
        placeholder="input user password"
        secureTextEntry={true}
        onChangeText={(userPwd) => this.setState({ userPwd })}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={style.loginBotton}
        onPress={this.handleSubmit}
      >
        <Text style={style.loginBottomText}>LOGIN</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state: AppState) => ({
    user: state.user
  }),
  { updateUser }
)(AppComponent)
```

The updateUser is a simple action like this.

```
// store/user/action.ts

import { UserState, UPDATE_USER } from './types'

export function updateUser(newUser: UserState) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_USER,
    payload: newUser
  }
}
```

But when I replace `updateUser` with `thunkLogin`, it report a error message show that it is not assignable for Props.

```
...

interface Props {
  thunkLogin: typeof thunkLogin
}

...

handleSubmit = () => {
  this.props.thunkLogin({
    userName: this.state.userName,
    userPwd: this.state.userPwd
  })
}

...

export default connect(
  (state: AppState) => ({
    user: state.user
  }),
  { thunkLogin }
)(AppComponent)
```

**UPDATE**
The error report

```
Argument of type 'typeof AppComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ user: UserState; } & { thunkLogin: (user: UserState) => void; }, Props>>'.
  Type 'typeof AppComponent' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Matching<{ user: UserState; } & { thunkLogin: (user: UserState) => void; }, Props>, any>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'Matching<{ user: UserState; } & { thunkLogin: (user: UserState) => void; }, Props>' is not assignable to type 'Props'.
        Types of property 'thunkLogin' are incompatible.
          Type '(user: UserState) => void' is not assignable to type '(user: UserState) => ThunkAction<void, { user: UserState; login: LoginState; }, null, Action<string>>'.
            Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ThunkAction<void, { user: UserState; login: LoginState; }, null, Action<string>>'. [2345]
```

Comment: `interface Props { thunkLogin: ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, Action<string>> }`

Comment: the `typeof thunkLogin` is the same as `ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, Action<string>>`

Comment: it's not, typeof thunkLogin is function

Comment: I add the type you advice, but get the same result.

Comment: @yuanlai Please let us know the exact error message.

Comment: I update the error report above

Comment: What did `props.updateUser` do? Did it dispatch an action i.e did something happen in a reducer? It looks like it returns an object.

Comment: @yuanlai Did you resolve the problem? I got a similar one